# Transform text values inside rows in spoilers? (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table like this generated with PHP and the content is fetched from MySQL.

```
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[2] . "</td>";
```

[image]

We can see the rows: **Genere**, **Download**
Inside the rows i have rispective ***text*** values,

```
Industrial Black Metal
Black Metal
Grindcore
```

I want transform the *text* values inside the cells in ***spoilers*** with inside text. 
*How Can i Do?*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use JavaScript. For example, you can use JavaScript library named jQuery.

Place this code somewhere on your page once:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".spoiler-label").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".spoiler-content").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, in your loop, instead of having just $row[2] etc., if you want to have a spoiler, use the following code (inside PHP tags, of course):

```
echo '<div>
    <span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[2].'</span>
    <div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none">Spoiler content</div>
</div>';
```

What you're doing here is hiding spoiler with display: none and then toggling it with jquery when label is clicked.

Comment: thanks..but i want see the hidden content when i click the text values inside the html table . I add your code but i have label out of html table. For example i want see hidden text when i click http://chilp.it/ad440f -- do u see the first link in **Download** column?

Comment: Another thing..if u looking the html table colors u can see that header<th> of row where contains spoilers is black while others have the color orange. http://imageshack.us/a/img443/548/spoiler2.png Why i lost formatting? This is my css for the page http://pastebin.com/yG1yHJA7